# Make Push-Notifications in Flutter with own Backend

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I am working on an app that has it's own backend. We want to send push-notifications from the backend to the devices of the user, and not use some Service like Firebase.

Now somehow I have to pass the device-ID to the backend, right?

Can anybody give me an idea of how this should / could work? Maybe also with code or links to articles how to access the device-id for the backend.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: It's a very long process, brother. I don't believe anyone wants to write the whole article in the answer. All you can do is to Google it "Flutter Notification Medium", and you may find many medium articles to go with. It will take your whole day to implement it & test it.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't expecting to get an entire code, just some impressions into it. Also googling wasn't really helpful, most solutions are with firebase and not with what I want for me. So I thought I ask here, maybe somebody got any links

Comment: Firebase is mandatory. It provides a bridge between your app & your server.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use Firebase Cloud Messaging or another implementation for pushes, you can send device token to your backend on app start - just make an HTTP request with the token to your server.